# Eclipse: how to create a workspace that doesn't modify the source directories?

Tags: eclipse

Environment: C++ makefile project, with sources on a (slow, shared) network drive. The sources are version controlled and I don't want to add any Eclipse files in the source tree.

Problem: I want to create a local workspace which doesn't write anything to the network drive, and I can't find a way to do this. I've tried half a dozen different things, including explicitly setting the build directory, linking to the top-level src directory, adding a src directory, explicitly setting the make command, changing the default file location, and so on, but I haven't found anything that works. Any ideas?

Comment: File -> New -> C++ Project.  Copy source files from network project to your local project.  When you're finished making changes, copy source from local project to your network project.  I use Java, and my personal projects are in the same work space as my work projects managed by Git.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc You should post that as an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @MC/GLB: not really an answer, unfortunately - I could just check out locally and mess up my own workspace, but that defeats (part of) the point, which is to keep the checked-out area clean.